# AngularJS v1.4.2 ng-bind-html and ng-bind-html-unsafe don't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I'm using AngularJS v1.4.2 and like to print out html from a variable in the `$scope`.

I tried to use `ng-bind-html` and `ng-bind-html-unsafe` but both are not working.

Here is my controller:

```
var ctrl = angular.module('app.ctrl',['app.model'])
        .controller('Controller',function($scope, $log, Model){
            $log.warn("controller für View wurde erstellt");
            $log.log(Model.getValue());
            $scope.sayHello="Hello World!";
            $scope.sayHelloHtml="<strong>Hello World Fett</strong>";
        });
```

And my HTML code:

```
...
<div ng-controller="Controller">Meine erste angularJS View {{ sayHello }}
<div ng-bind="sayHello"></div>
<div ng-bind-html="sayHelloHtml"></div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: _"Don't work"_? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: HTML content in variables has to be trusted, else the HTML is stripped out.  use the `$sce` to trust your HTML content.  see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Answer (score 3):

```
var ctrl = angular.module('app.ctrl',['app.model','ngSanitize'])
        .controller('Controller',function($scope, $log, Model,'$sce'){
            $log.warn("controller für View wurde erstellt");
            $log.log(Model.getValue());
            $scope.sayHello="Hello World!";
            $scope.sayHelloHtml="<strong>Hello World Fett</strong>";

            $scope.sayHelloHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.sayHelloHtml);
        });
```

HTML

```
 <div ng-controller="Controller">Meine erste angularJS View {{ sayHello }}
            <div ng-bind="sayHello"></div>
            <div ng-bind-html="sayHelloHtml"></div>
            <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="sayHello"></div>
            </div>
```

Make sure you have include **angular-sanitize.js** and injected **ngSanitize** module in app and injected **$sce** in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to use the $sce ([Strict Contextual Escaping service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce))

$scope.sayHelloHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml("**Hello World Fett**");

Answer (score 0):

according to the docs for ng-bind-html you need to add ngSanitize to your module dependencies for it to work correctly, which looks like you didn't ;)

Check the example on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml for further details.

Cheers
D